# How to migrate bacula jobs

Tags: linux, backup, bacula

All my bacula jobs are writing to one file. How can I migrate these jobs to separate files, I have a 1G limit. I've already marked the volume as full, and yet, the volume is still being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add new volumes to the existing pool, which will then start to be written to automatically. It sounds like you're using files as your volumes, so adding new files and labeling them into the existing storage pool should cause them to start being used.

You could also setup a new storage pool, populate it with volumes, and then modify the jobs to write to the new storage pool.

Comment: I would like to migrate these backups away from the volume they are in, because that volume is +1TB, and I don't like the idea of having a file that large with all my backups in it.